# Django. Отображение документа на странице

Tags: html, python, django

Проблема следующая:
Есть страница, на которой нужно отображать расписание. Само расписание загружается ежемесячно в формате .docx. Причем, составляется довольно хитро и ни разу не однообразно.

Цель: отображать расписание на страничке.

Вопрос: как это сделать? Повторюсь, парсить этот doc-ский документ, распихивать его по моделькам очень сложно. Намного проще было бы загрузить все расписание целиком и целиком отображать на страницке весь doc-ский документ. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Так что вы хотите в результате получить? Таблицу в html? Картинку? Текстовый блок?

Comment: Таблицу. либо отображение содержимого документа "как есть".

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте использовал конвертацию `docx` в `jpg` и отображал бы картинкой. Для этого есть различные `API`, как платные, так и бесплатные (самому это будет сделать сложно).

Comment: В pdf, а пдф рендерится яваскриптом в хтмл